# How to generate a user readable report in Cypress?

Tags: testing, cypress

How to generate a cypress report which can be understood by a person who has no knowledge on software.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress allows you to generate a report using any supported Mocha reporter, or even specify a custom one. I would suggest that you look at the [Cypress reporters](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters) documentation. I'd also throw in [Mochawesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochawesome) as a pretty nice reporter that requires little understanding of the software to grasp.